# C++11 in Eclipse Without Specifying "-std=c++11" for Each Project

Tags: eclipse, c++11, compiler-errors, eclipse-kepler

I'm using Eclipse Kepler for C++, and I'm trying to update to C++11.

I've found that appending "-std=c++11" under C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags will enable a specific project to run C++11. However, I have not been able to find a way to default this operation whenever a new project is created.

Is there a one-time setting that automatically sets a new C++ project to C++11? Thanks for letting me know.